# Limit Voronoi's polygons to calculate areas

Tags: python, voronoi

Where can I find a set of criteria to limit unbounded Voronoi's polygons?
Does anyone know if are there python functions implementing those criteria?

I have a set of points in 2D and I need to have areas for the resulting Voronoi areas.

Thanks

Comment: hmmm... If there are no ones who did that already in Python, I think you have to figure out what algorithms are related (as math) and try implementing them in Python!
By the way, Is this related? [Algorithms and Criteria for Volumetric Centroidal
Voronoi Tessellations](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01681017/document)

Comment: @MohamadGhaithAlzin thanks. This seems to be a description of a case that works when you know the shape of the element of which the area is searched. For me, it is the  other way around. I have a set of points and I want to calculate their Voronoi's area corresponding to each of them. I feel it is a well-known problem, already solved... but... but... :..(

Comment: Well, if you provide the math I would help to write it in Python. However, if you try to ask specialized people in such a domain if found on the [stackexchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites). There are lots of sites so my suggestion is that you try to ask in the most related one to your problem.

Comment: This is an example![creating-voronoi-polygons-from-polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194009/creating-voronoi-polygons-from-polygons?newreg=cef5b8aff4da4221a10cc6599a0f28ef)